# With Asp.net Mvc I would like to select multiple languages in which members can speak using Dropdownlist in a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I didn't understand how to send and save the selected languages.

When I use Plugin (select2), there is a problem with Js and other Plugin in the template.

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Which Languages Speak *</label>
<span style="color:red;"><small>    >>> You can select multiple languages.</small></span>
<div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" style="max-width: 100%;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
<select class="form-control" name="Dil_Id[]" multiple="multiple" id="select" required>
@foreach (var item in dilList)
{
<option value="@item.Id">@item.DilAdi_Eng</option>
}
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class YeniIhtiyacSahibiController : Controller
{
    // GET: IhtiyacSahibi/YeniIhtiyacSahibi
    IhtiyacSahibiUyeBLL _ISUye = new IhtiyacSahibiUyeBLL();
    ISUDilBLL _isuDil = new ISUDilBLL(); // members languages

    public ActionResult Index(int Id = 0)
    {
        var model = _ISUye.GetById(Id);
        ViewBag.Mesaj = GenelAraclarBLL.KayitYeni(); // Message Succesfull
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IhtiyacSahibiUye model)
    {
            return View(model);

    }
}
```

What can i do without plugin and how can i send and save that items?  I don't know how to make and send the list. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I post forms with select2 like this:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/Projects/Edit/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,

            ProjectManagersString: $("#ProjectManagers").val(),  //select 2 control value

        }
    })
```

Controller:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Project project)
    {

            if (Request.Form["ProjectManagersString[]"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var pmstring in Request.Form["ProjectManagersString[]"].Split(','))
                {

                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding of the form controls is done in the parameter indicated in the Post method of the controller. Following an example to access the selected value.

**The Model**

```
public class Mymodel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> dilList { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
public class YeniIhtiyacSahibiController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
     //Get Method
      return View(model);
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(IhtiyacSahibiUye model)
   {
     car selectedId=model.Id
    return View(model);
   }
}
```

**The View**

```
@model namespace.Models.Mymodel 
@{
    Layout = null;
} 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "YeniIhtiyacSahibiController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    DilAdi_Eng:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.dilList, "Language")
                </td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Cordialement